# How can const be applied to template argument types outside of the parameter list in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, constants

I am studying C++ templates, and I got stuck thinking about the interaction between const and types that are arguments to template functions. Specifically, I am thinking about how consts interact with template types when applied outside of the template parameter list.

I have tried looking for this interaction in C++ Primer 5th ed (Lippman) and in the C++11 standard draft, but const in this context is either not explicitly mentioned or (in the case of the standard) rather complex in its description (I'm still somewhat new to C++).

Here is a code example of my problem:

```cpp
template<typename T>
const T & constify(T & t) {
    return t;
}

...

int* i = 0x12345678; 
constify(i);
```

I have two different expectations of the return type:

1. The deduced return type is `const (int *) &`, i.e the const is applied afterwards, so that we cannot modify the int pointer but we can modify what it points to.
2. The deduced return type is `const int * &`, i.e all declarators and qualifiers are applied all at once instead of as in 1. Here, we can no longer modify the int pointed to by the integer, but we can modify the pointer itself.

For me, the first one makes more sense because it has a natural "substitution-like" rule behind it, similar to typedef. But my question is; which of these (if any) is correct and why?

Comment: #1 is correct, because that's what the language spec says. `T` is `int*`, a pointer to `int`. So `const T` is `int* const` - const pointer to `int`, not a pointer to const `int`. `const` doesn't jump into the middle of the type.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Template type substitutions are not textual, so do not think of them in terms of the textual type definition.

In your example, T is deduced to be `int *` - let's call it `intptr`. You are making `const` reference to it, so return value becomes `const intptr&`. That means, that the pointer itself can't be modified through this reference, but the value it points to can be modified.

Last, but not the least, you could have easily verifed your assumptions before asking the question :)

Comment: This answer was exactly what I was looking for, thank you! So essentially, a typename can be thought of as a type alias in how it interacts with declarators and qualifiers? (My apologies for not verifying beforehand)

Answer (score 5):

The 1st one is correct, and the return type would be `int * const &`, i.e. the reference to **`const` pointer** to non-const `int`; not `const int * &`, i.e. the reference to non-const pointer to `const` `int`.

`const` is qualified on `T` itself, when `T` is a pointer `const T` would be a `const` pointer but not a pointer to `const` pointee.

Answer (score 3):

`const` *consistent* location is on the right of the type. Some declarations, like variables, also allow putting `const` on the left, but others, like member function definitions, only allow `const` on the right.

If you always put/apply `const` on the right it helps you to think about it in the right way. This is the reason many boost libraries put `const` on the right.

`constify` apples `const` on the right, hence, it turns `T` that is `int*` into `int* const` - a constant pointer to non-constant `int`. And apply the reference on the right of that: `int* const&`.